# Print template data in Portals

Tags: liquid, dynamics-crm-portals

I want to know what data is avalible to me in a portal template, but it doesn't output anything.

I've tried printing the sitemap like this

```
{% sitemap | json %}
```

But that doesn't yield anything, so I tried

```
{% for x in sitemap %}
    {% for y in x %}
        {{ y }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But still nothing. Any tips to get any data? Preferably the root data object, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level node in the sitemap object is `sitemap.root`. There are additional properties on the sitemap node objects that need to be accessed to output information.

Here's an example of rendering out the root sitemap node and its child pages, by accessing the `children` property of the root node, and the `url` and `title` of each child sitemap node.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="{{sitemap.root.url}}">{{ sitemap.root.title }}</a>
    <ul>
      {% for child in sitemap.root.children %}
      <li><a href="{{child.url}}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/liquid-objects#sitemap) for the sitemap object for more information on its structure.